# How to convert CYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I have data in a CYYMMDD date format which I need to convert into YYYY-MM-DD in SSIS Package.
How to achieve this?
Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: give some examples of CYYMMDD. You just need to replace that C with 19 or 20 is my guess. And then convert that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your  CYYMMDD column is called cdate and let's call the transformed date ydate then you may need a Derived Column transformation with this expression:

```
LEFT(cdate,1) == "0" 
? "19" + SUBSTRING(cdate,2,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(cdate,4,2) + "-" + RIGHT(cdate,2) 
: "20" + SUBSTRING(cdate,2,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(cdate,4,2) + "-" + RIGHT(cdate,2)
```

result:

[image]